# How to fire a input change automatically?

Tags: jquery

The`<input type="text">` submit the entry after a click outside of it.

How can I submit the input automatically?

```
<input type="text" name="sQuantity" id="sQuantity" value="1" onchange="onChangeInput()" onblur="onBlurInput()">
```

My try:

```
$( "#sQuantity" ).change(function() {
  $( "body" ).click(); 
});
```

Comment: Use `keyup` event.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? By "accept the input automatically?" do you mean submit the input?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use keyup or keydown

```
$( "#sQuantity" ).keyup(function() {
    $( "body" ).click(); 
});
```

You can also use onKeyup instead of onChange on the input as well.

```
<input type="text" name="sQuantity" id="sQuantity" value="1" onKeyup="onChangeInput()">
```

And here is some info on keyup and how it works https://api.jquery.com/keyup/

Answer (score 0):

you can use keyup event like this :

```
<input id="sQuantity" onchange="onChangeInput();"  value="1" type="text"
onkeyup="this.onchange();" onpaste="this.onchange();" oninput="this.onchange();  onblur="onBlurInput()""/>
```